# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object using laravel

Tags: laravel

i am beginner at laravel,I am trying to update data but unfortunately i am facing error how to fix it ? Does anyone have an idea please help me thanks.
please see this error https://flareapp.io/share/Lm839R5v

**controller**

```
  public function update(Request $request, $cms)
  {
       $cms = CMS::findOrFail($cms);
       $request->validate([
      'text'      => 'required',
       ]);

       $cms->text      = $request->text;
       $cms->type      = 16;
       $cms->save();
       return response()->json('Updated successfully', 200);
   }
```

**Route**

```
 Route::get('/pages/election','ElectionController@index')->name('about.elections');
 Route::put('/pages/election/{cms}/update', "ElectionController@update")- 
 >name('about.elctions.update');
```

Comment: put your blade file code...

Comment: First use dd($elections) if you are receiving data from controller or not. Additionally What other routes do you have ? Post other routes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see the problem is not in the controller code, problem is in `election-js.blade.php` at line 12:

```
axios.post('{{route('about.elctions.update',$elections->id)}}',
```

Which means you need to check `$elections` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$elections->id` is the problem. Maybe there's no data in `$elections` and when you are trying to fetch `id` property, it can not find anything. That's where the error is.